# Hosts with both gigabit and 10GBE NICs

Tags: routing, 10gbase

I have both a gigabit network (all Mac Pros, gigabit switch) and a 10gig network (subset of hosts using Sonnet Twin 10G adapters, 10BGbase-T switch). How do I get machine pairs where both have 10gig to talk to each other using the 10gig NICs, but keep machine pairs where only one (or both) have only gigabit ethernet to use the gigabit network?

In other words, hostA and hostB have 10gig (and gigabit), hostC only has gigabit. I want A and B to talk 10gig, but A and C should talk gigabit. How do I get B to show up in A's Finder's under the 'shared' section and when connected, talk 10gig rather than gigabit, and at the same time, when mounting a shared volume from C have that end up via gigabit ethernet?

I do have a DNS server (via OS X server) that has entries for hostAX and hostBX as the 10gig IP addresses. But the user sees hostA, not hostAX in Finder and hostA (per the DNS) is a gigabit, not a 10gig address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The hosts don't have to have same-speed nics to talk to each others. You can perfectly establish communication between host A - using 10G - and host C - using 1G.

If you're not comfortable with dual-homing hosts, I strongly suggest you only connect the 10G adapters on 10G capable machines, and everything should be fine.

If the 10G and 1G networks are not interconnected at layer 2, then you need to have routing between them.